# What "neutral culture" breaks DateTime.TryParse()?

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

I have the following code snippet

```
DateTime date1;
CultureInfo neutralCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
bool isNeutral = neutralCulture.IsNeutralCulture; // True

DateTime.TryParse("not a date", neutralCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date1);
```

Which executes without throwing an exception, however, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx) states

> NotSupportedException: *provider* is **a** neutral culture and cannot be used in a parsing operation.

`"fr"` is **a** neutral culture, as demonstrated by the property on the `CultureInfo` object above, so I would expect this code to break.

What "neutral culture" breaks this method - is this documented anywhere?

Comment: It seems that the Exception is thrown when trying to *set the Thread culture* to a neutral culture. I did not have time to look through all reference sources, but you might want to dive in yourself: (1) https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs and (2) https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs

Comment: Why do you expect an exception? If the string dpes not represent a date TryParse shpuld simply return false... I don't exactly understand the remark in the documentation but it seems to me that it does not refer to the string you are passing at all...

Comment: I am expecting an exception because the documentation states the exception would occur if that particular parameter is a neutral culture.

Comment: May be this is for some custom provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test of all the neutral cultures, and not even one threw an exception as shown below:

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
foreach (var thisCulture in cultures)
{
    DateTime date1;
    CultureInfo neutralCulture = new CultureInfo(thisCulture.Name);
    bool isNeutral = neutralCulture.IsNeutralCulture; // True

    DateTime.TryParse("not a date", neutralCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date1);
}
```

I am not sure what to conclude from that. Could the documentation be wrong? Who knows.

Comment: Usually when this happens it is because someone copied and pasted the documentation of a existing similar method that may have more restrictive constraints than the method with the wrong documentation. I have seen this happen before in the MSDN docs.

Comment: I'll take this as the solution until someone else digs up more specific lore here :D